# MVC attribute routing issues

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I decorate an action (in my Home controller) like so:

```
[Route("view-book")]
public ActionResult ViewBook(int? id1, string id2)
```

In my View, I populate some hyperlinks using javascript:

```
tbody = tbody + '<a href="@Url.Action("ViewBook", "Home")/' + item.Id + '/' + item.Slug + '">View Book</a>';
```

With the above code, the URL of the hyperlink renders correctly.  E.g:

```
https://localhost:44306/view-book/1/this-book
```

However, the ActionResult doesn't get hit.  So, I change the routing decoration to be:

```
[Route("view-book/{id1:int?}/{id2}")]
public ActionResult ViewBook(int? id1, string id2)
```

And now the URL renders incorrectly like so:

```
https://localhost:44306/Home/ViewBook/1/this-prop
```

However, if I manually change the URL to the correct URL like above:

```
https://localhost:44306/view-book/1/this-prop
```

The ActionResult then gets hit!

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use multiple routes on the action.

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("view-book")] // Matches GET view-book
[Route("view-book/{id1:int?}/{id2}")] //Matches GET view-book/1/slug
public ActionResult ViewBook(int? id1, string id2) { ... }
```

That way, when you build the route in javascript, the first route should now allow you to render the correct URL before because `@Url.Action("ViewBook", "Home")` should resolve to `view-book` as desired, and the second route will allow the action to be invoked.